# ForeignKey not displayed in Tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Fields defined in my models as models.ForeignKey are not displayed in Tastypie. All fields are displayed except Client field.
Quick and dirty fix is to add another field in Statement model like

```
ClientID = models.IntegerField(db_column='Client_id', max_length=32)
```

but this seems wrong to me. Does anyone know better solution?

models.py

```
class Client(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    F1 = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    F2 = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)


class Statement(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='statements')
    State = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
```

api.py

```
class StatementResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Statement.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'client'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        include_resource_uri = False

class ClientResource(ModelResource):
    statements = fields.ToManyField(StatementResource, 'statements', null=True, blank=True, full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Client.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'client'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        include_resource_uri = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Tastypie you have to define all relational fields in ModelResources definition. So if you got some let say foreign key in model you have to define that foreign key again in model resource. The reason for that is Tastypie has to know how to deal if it. Has to know serialization, authorization, authentication, etc for it. Other ways the field be ignored. You have to pass that related resource and that's it.

```
class StatementResource(ModelResource):
    Client = fields.ForeignKey(ClientResource, 'Client')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Statement.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'client'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        include_resource_uri = False
```

Comment: If I include this line in StatementResource: "Client = fields.ForeignKey(ClientResource, 'Client')", Error "name 'ClientResource' is not defined" will occur. Should I define ClientResource before StatementResource than there should be error regarding StatementResource not being defined.

Comment: Using singlequote around ClientResource like "Client = fields.ForeignKey('ClientResource', 'Client')" solved this problem. Thanks